# Populating filter criteria and custom filter logic on Reports through URL

Tags: reporting

I have a custom report saved with no filter criteria. When calling it, I populate the criteria through the URL, so that the final URL looks something like:

```
https://na7.salesforce.com/00OA000000xxxZG?pc0=00NA0000xxxku0A&pc1=00NA00000xxxIed
&pn0=eq&pn1=ge&pv0=55979&pv1=8%2F20%2F2012
```

This works fine and fills in up to 10 filter criteria. However, I don't seem to be able to use the bool_filter parameter to configure custom logic. From my understanding, the format should look like `bool_filter=(1+OR+2)+AND+3`. When this parameter is in the URL, I am directed to the Customize Report screen instead of displaying the report itself, and none of my criteria are reflected.

It seems possible to me that this might be a result of my report having no criteria in place initially, and maybe therefore "1 and 2" don't have any reference for bool_filter. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I knew about `pv0` etc, but not about `pc0` and `pn0`.  Awesome!  Sorry I don't know about the `bool_filter`, though.

Comment: In some cases, the values to use for pc are the actual field Ids, as above. In older report types, they seem to be IDs unique to that report type. You can see them by Viewing Source on a report screen and looking for the picklist optgroups.

Comment: Is it worth trying "%20" to URL encode the spaces rather than "+"? Ref [Changing Salesforce report filters through url - change the Filter Logic too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932960/changing-salesforce-report-filters-through-url-change-the-filter-logic-too) and [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

Comment: I have actually tried it both ways, with `+` and with `%20`. Same result so far. Thanks for the links, I had looked at the Salesforce one before, which is what got me this far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. The bool_filter parameter can only refer to criteria rows that are *saved* in the Report. My "template" report was saved with no criteria, so that I could add them one at a time. So when bool_filter refers to `1 AND (2 OR 3)`, those filter rows don't exist in the saved report, and it doesn't know what to do.

Solution for me: I saved the report with 10 filter rows, each of which is `Created Date not equal ''`. Then I change what fields and values those filter rows are pointing to, and make sure the bool_filter parameter includes all integers 1 through 10. The final URL looks like this:
    `https://tapp0.salesforce.com/00OA0000004m4ZG?bool_filter=%28%281+AND+2%29+OR+%283+AND+4%29%29+AND+5+AND+6+AND+7+AND+8+AND+9+AND+10
&pc0=00NA0000009ku0A&pc1=00NA0000007jIed&pc2=00NA0000007jIed&pc3=00NA0000007jIed&pc4=00NA0000007jIed
&pn0=eq&pn1=ge&pn2=le&pn3=ge&pn4=le
&pv0=abc&pv1=8%2F21%2F2012&pv2=8%2F21%2F2012&pv3=8%2F21%2F2012&pv4=8%2F21%2F2012`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a report with 10 filter criteria, you need to include all 10 in your bool_filter statement.

bool_filter=(1+OR+2)+AND+3+AND+4+AND+5+AND+6+AND+7+AND+8+AND+9+AND+10

Or whatever logic you wish...