# URL for a specific set of Opportunities

Tags: force.com

In Salesforce it is possible to get a unique URL for every opportunitiy.
It is of the form:

```
http://{server_name}/{opportunity.ID}
```

Is it possible to get a URL for:

- All opportunities that are won?
- All opportunities that are open?
- All opportunities that have not been updated in last 30 days?

These URLs would returned lists of Opportunities.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create list views on the opportunity based on the desired criteria and each list view will have a unique url per org.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Report that shows the list you like, and then link to that Report. Potentially you can include URL parameters that will modify the Report Criteria as well: [One example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/673/populating-filter-criteria-and-custom-filter-logic-on-reports-through-url)