# What is the URL parameter for populating Cross object filters on reports?

Tags: reporting

I'm familiar with the standard report URL parameters (pv0, pc0, etc.) as discussed in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/673/populating-filter-criteria-and-custom-filter-logic-on-reports-through-url) question but they don't appear to work for cross object filters. I am reporting on Accounts and trying to dynamically set the following filter:

```
Accounts without Contacts
      Type EQUALS {!from_url}
```

Is there a URL parameter that will work for this or another way to dynamically fill in the filters and run this report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is old, but check out this site, it is definitely possible.

http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/06/03/url-hacking-cross-filter-reports/

This posts lists the following parameters:

> ptable0 – This parameter corresponds to the main object in your
>   report. I haven’t quite figured out what goes here, but it seems to be
>   CUST_ID for custom objects and [OBJECT NAME]_ID for standard objects.
>
> ocond0 – Use w for with and wo for without
>
> rtable0 – This is the cross filtered object. It should be the object
>   name for standard objects and the object ID for custom ones.
>
> rtablecol0 – This is the column on the cross filtered object that
>   corresponds to the parent object.  For standard objects, use the field
>   name and and for custom objects, use the field ID.
>
> sfpc0_0 – This is the field to filter on. For standard objects, use
>   the field name and and for custom objects, use the field ID.
>
> sfpn0_0 – This is the filter operator. It can be values such as eq,
>   ne, gt, lt, ge, le.
>
> sfpv0_0 – This is the value you want to filter on.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find one a while back and came up short. I don't believe this exists.