# How to show Dashboard report from certain campaign

Tags: dashboard, campaign, reports-api

I've developed a report with dashboard and its already placed on a certain campaign. By doing that the report is shown to all other campaigns, something that i don't want it like that.
I want that specific report to be placed in the specific campaign. Not same report in all campaigns.

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

I would create a more generic report matching to all or most campaigns and invoke it by a button or link. You can use some URL parameters to pass arguments as filters:

[Populating filter criteria and custom filter logic on Reports through URL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/673/populating-filter-criteria-and-custom-filter-logic-on-reports-through-url)

If you want to see an embedded report chart or the button mentioned above only on a specific campaigns check page-layouts and record-types:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=layouts_assigning.htm&language=en_US